# fix "class not found: android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener" after migration to nativescript 6.0

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm migrating nativescript from 5.3 to 6.0.1 and getting support libraries error.

> Gradle build...
>            + setting applicationId
>            + applying user-defined configuration from C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle
>            Applying settings from C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\app\App_Resources\Android\settings.json
>            + using andorid X library androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
>            + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\node_modules\nativescript-background-http\platforms\android\nativescript_background_http.aar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\node_modules\nativescript-camera\platforms\android\nativescript_camera.aar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\node_modules\nativescript-imagepicker\platforms\android\nativescript_imagepicker.aar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\node_modules\nativescript-loading-indicator\platforms\android\nativescript_loading_indicator.aar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\node_modules\nativescript-plugin-firebase\platforms\android\firebase-release.aar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\node_modules\nativescript-plugin-firebase\platforms\android\nativescript_plugin_firebase.aar
>            + adding jar plugin dependency: C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\node_modules\nativescript-webview-interface\platforms\android\WebViewInterface.jar
>            + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\parth.maisheri\native-repo\unite (2.0
>   final-realese)\unite\node_modules\tns-core-modules-widgets\platforms\android\widgets-release.aar
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask
>   is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Class not found
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getClass(Generator.java:549)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getInterfacesFromCache(Generator.java:532)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBinding(Generator.java:283)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBinding(Generator.java:171)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.processRows(Generator.java:234)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBindings(Generator.java:121)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:97)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:50)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:runSbg'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Support libraries are no longer supported, are you using `nativescript-pulltorefresh` plugin? If yes, upgrade to it's latest for compatibility with {N} v6.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because I was using the deprecated component

Make sure you are using the [@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh) component (not the deprecated "nativescript-pulltorefresh").

run this command to add the plugin:

```
tns plugin add @nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh
```

If so, update it to latest version

Then check if the right component is referred correctly

```
registerElement("PullToRefresh", () => require("@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh").PullToRefresh);
```